# set adapter in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-gridview

Getting this error: [image] 
I am trying to show gridview in fragment but this error occurs while i am setting the adapter .

My fragment is like this:

```
public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment {


GridView gv;
Context context;
ArrayList prgmName;
public static String [] prgmNameList={"Adventure","Animals","Automotive","Foods","Diy","Business","Technology","Creative Art","Entertainment"};
public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.adventure,R.drawable.animals,R.drawable.automobiles,R.drawable.food_and_drinks,R.drawable.diy,R.drawable.business,R.drawable.technology,R.drawable.creativity,R.drawable.entertainment};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore,container,false);
    gv=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_explore_gridView1);
    gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter((MainActivity) getContext().getApplicationContext(),prgmNameList,prgmImages));
}
```

Please correct me here.

Comment: You are missing a return statement, which is the "view" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Comment `return super` and add `return view` at end

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore,container,false);
        gv=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_explore_gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter((MainActivity) getContext().getApplicationContext(),prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line below set adapter line

```
return view;
```

Your onCreateView will look like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore,container,false);
        gv=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_explore_gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter((MainActivity) getContext().getApplicationContext(),prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

return the view after inflating

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore,container,false);
        gv=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_explore_gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter((MainActivity) getContext().getApplicationContext(),prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        return view;
    }
```